# Cycles render no material in full render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I can't render all materials in full render. All materials are just replaced with Marble (one of my materials). However, it works in viewport render.

Link:  https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1zTVV2u9-ZR4fEmytC-8yVmQ7eHPdbaHa6uDRXX2L_og/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you have set a Material Override in the [Render Layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/layers.html) tab > Layer panel > Material field. Clear it, and your materials should reappear.